# Client finished message in TLS v1.0

Tags: ssl

JKJS

"Client finished message is encryption of all handshake messages".

But it is not clear:

1)Does it contain only handshake messages sent by client?
2)Does it contain only handshake messages received from server?
3)Or does it contain both of above?
4)Does handshake messages contain 'change cipher spec' message?

Please help me.

JKJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finished Message will contain the Handshake Messages sent from both the Server and Client. It will not contain the Change Cipher Spec Message as it is not considered as part of Handshake Messages.

The below paragraph in RFC 2246 explains it well:

> The hash contained in finished messages sent by the server incorporate Sender.server; those sent by the client incorporate Sender.client. The value handshake_messages includes all handshake messages starting at client hello up to, but not including, this finished message. This may be different from handshake_messages in Section 7.4.8 because it would include the certificate verify message (if sent). Also, the handshake_messages for the finished message sent by the client will be different from that for the finished message sent by the server, because the one which is sent second will include the prior one.
>
> > **Note:** Change cipher spec messages, alerts and any other record types are not handshake messages and are not included in the hash computations. Also, Hello Request messages are omitted from handshake hashes.